# How VPN affects other users on the same network?

Tags: vpn

My friend is using a VPN for an online game, because our network is through a proxy server and some ports a blocked. Sometimes my internet connection interrupts, so may VPN somehow influence other clients on same network?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it shouldn't unless traffic shaping is done which might give your friends connection a higher QoS. But that is really dependent on your network setup. But even with QoS, your connection should not get interrupted, only slown down.